# Angular bind only when mouse moves

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

I have a very weird problem. I've got an input and I want to show a button only when the input has a value. It's working only if i move the mouse.

```
<input class="form-control"
   type="text"
   placeholder="hello there..."
   #helloInput
>

{{helloInput.value}} --> not shows until mouse is moving

<button class="btn btn-success"
   *ngIf="helloInput.value"
>Show me</button>
```

It's very weird. Any idea?

Comment: Can you make stackblitz example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular updates view only by calling change detection. Most of the time it happens automatically because of Event listeners/XHR/setTimeout/setInterval calls.

In your example there's no any event listener known by Angular. Since it's updated by mousemove then there's some listener for it and Angular detected that.

In order to update your view on any input value change you can simply add empty `input` event listener:

```
<input class="form-control"
   type="text"
   placeholder="hello there..."
   #helloInput
   (input)="0"  <=============== this one
>
```

Comment: So Angular doesn't run change detection on keyup or keydown events?

Comment: It does run cd on `keyup` and `keydown` but in your scenarios there're no such listeners. I used `input` event here because it handles more cases like copy/pasting value

Comment: Try replacing `(input)` with `(keyup)` or `(keydown)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've changed with (keyup) and it's working now